# W3 total cache plugin multiple instances install

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed "W3 Total Cache" plugin, but my environment has right now only one instance, and works ok. How can I replicate this configuration on multiple instances? I'm using elasticbeanstalk from amazon.

Comment: Multiple instances of what?

Comment: ec2 instance (Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud) any my app is running there.